# Changing Primary Key Without Changing Foreign Keys (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database-schema, liquibase

I have a table of entities which each have an `id` and a `name`. `name` is our original primary key, but to support quick renaming we are trying to transition from using `name` to using `id` as primary key and in all foreign keys.

What I'm trying to do is switch without needing to (initially) drop the foreign keys. In a sense, I need to replace the primary key on `name` with a unique constraint on `name` so I can add a primary key on `id`. I had thought this statement would work:

`ALTER TABLE table_1 DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (name), ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)`

Which fails with this response: `Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint`. A little more detail from the InnoDB error log:

```
Error in foreign key constraint of table schema_name/table_2:
there is no index in referenced table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
referenced table do not match the ones in table. Constraint:

CONSTRAINT "fk_table_1_t1name_external" FOREIGN KEY ("external", "t1_name") REFERENCES "table_1" ("external", "name") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
The index in the foreign key in table is "fk_table_1_t1name_external"
```

The weirdest thing is, the change still takes effect:

```
name    varchar(80) NO  UNI     
id      varchar(40) NO  PRI
```

Is there a way to get rid of this error, or a better way to perform this change? We use liquibase for our DB change management so a change-set that causes an error prevents any subsequent changes even if the change set still processes as intended.

Comment: Have you tried adding the new unique constraint first, in a separate query, before changing the primary key?

Comment: @Uueerdo just verified, produces the same error. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Interesting update: Looks like the only foreign keys that produce the error of all the ones referencing this name column reference this _pair_ of columns in `table_1`: `FOREIGN KEY ("external", "t1_name") REFERENCES "table_1" ("external", "name")` (Our schema has 2 such keys, both referencing `"table_1" ("external", "name")`. I may be able to push forward, but I'm still curious as to why the above foreign keys are causing errors with this change

Comment: Your problem description and initially presented ALTER suggest a single-field index/FK; but your error log show a two-field scenario. If the FK references two fields, the unique key must be on both fields. Even this may not resolve the problem though, MySQL may be tying the FK to the index when the FK is created; you may have to drop the FK, change the indexes, and then recreate the FK to avoid any errors.

Comment: @Uueerdo I think this is what was going on. Issue was resolved by creating an index on `(external, name)` (there was an existing one on `external` which I replaced) and then dropping and re-adding the foreign keys. Thanks for the help!